# LINQ, type cannot be inferred

Tags: linq

I am currently learning LINQ, when performing this query:

```
public static class Linq
       {
           // Returns the given anonymous method as a lambda expression
           public static Expression<Func<Int32, Int32>>
              Expr<T, R>(Expression<Func<Int32, Int32>> f)
           {
               return f;
           }
           // Returns the given anonymous function as a Func delegate
           public static Func<T, R>
                 Func<T, R>(Func<T, R> f)
           {
               return f;
           }

   }

//main Fun

var expr = Linq.Expr((Int32 a, Int32 b) => a + b);
var fun = Linq.Func((int a, int b) => a + b);
```

I get the following error `Linq.Expr<T,R>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<int,int>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the point of the members of your `static class Linq` here? They are simply returning exactly what is passed to them.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Not quite true. Try writing the last two lines without these methods. You would need to perform either a cast or explicitly specify the type of the variables. These methods are a shortcut for this. Shortcut as in "shorter to type" :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Well, what I said is true, but I see what you mean - they provide a concrete type for the compiler to know what to do with the `var` keywords. Makes sense, now. :-) EDIT: What I posted was not complete, and in that sense, not quite true. Yes :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Yes. What I meant with "not quite true" is: They are not only returning what is passed to them, but they are also forcing an implicit conversion from a lambda expression to a strongly typed variable - and this is the real benefit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have two input parameters and one return value, you need to use a `Func<T1, T2, TRet>`, i.e. one with three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
public static class Linq { 
// Returns the given anonymous method as a lambda expression 
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2, R>> 
                    Expr<T1, T2, R>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, R>> f) 
      { 
    return f; 
} 
// Returns the given anonymous function as a Func delegate 
public static Func<T1, T2, R> Func<T1, T2, R>(Func<T1, T2, R> f) 
{ 
    return f; 
}}
```

Usage:

```
var expr = Linq.Expr<int, int, int>((a, b) => a + b);
var fun =  Linq.Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => a + b);
```